# Grouping string into substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, group-by, python-itertools

I need some explanation as to how this code works. I do not understand the need for 'str' and 'grp' within the for loop. What are they keeping track of?

```
from itertools import groupby
print(["".join(grp) for str, grp in groupby('aaacaccccccbbbb')])
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)?

Comment: This is a joining the grouped items (iterators of strings) created by `groupby`.  See the docs and this post for more explanations https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873519/4531270

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` groups consecutive iterators by some `key`. If no key is specified, the default grouping predicate is that the consecutive elements should be the same. So, to summarise, `groupby` groups identical consecutive elements together.

Exhausting the `groupby`, you see it returns tuples:

```
list(groupby('aaacaccccccbbbb'))

[('a', <itertools._grouper at 0x12f132a58>),
 ('c', <itertools._grouper at 0x12f132d30>),
 ('a', <itertools._grouper at 0x12f132cf8>),
 ('c', <itertools._grouper at 0x12f1b9da0>),
 ('b', <itertools._grouper at 0x12f1a68d0>)]
```

Each tuple is a pair of `<group_key, [group_values_iterator]>`, which corresponds to `str` and `grp` in the list comprehension. `grp` is basically the elements in that group. The list comprehension is exhausting the `grp` iterator and joining the characters together.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use built-ins as variable names: `str,int,set,dict,tuple,list,max,min,...`

If in doubt, dissabssemble list comprehensions into its parts and supply them to print statements ([How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)):

```
from itertools import groupby
grouping = groupby('aaacaccccccbbbb')

for stri, grp in grouping: 
    print(stri)              # key of the grouping
    print(list(grp))         # group (use list to show it instead of the groupingiterable)
    print("")
```

Output:

```
a
['a', 'a', 'a']

c
['c']

a
['a']

c
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']

b
['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

If you still got questions about it, read the API or search SO: [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby)