# Finding two elements in list with same attribute in Python

Tags: python, list, oop, dictionary, attributes

I want to find any pair of elements in a list that have the same attribute. For example,

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

my_list = [X(1), X(2), X(3), X(2), X(3), X(3)]
```

So if comparing on `x.param`, I'd be looking for `my_list[1], my_list[3]` or `my_list[2], my_list[4]` or `my_list[2], my_list[5]` or `my_list[4], my_list[5]`. However, there's no guarantee that the list would necessary have any elements with the same property, e.g.

```
my_list = [X(1), X(2), X(3)]
```

might also be a valid parameter to this function.

The obvious way to do this seems to be:

```
def find_dupe(my_list, my_lambda):
    attrs = dict()
    for item in my_list:
        if my_lambda(item) in attrs:
             return [attrs[my_lambda(item)], item]
        attrs[my_lambda(item)] = item
    return []
```

But it seems a bit inelegant and I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to do this.

Comment: sounds like a job for [itertools.groupby()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby) - get all groups with > 1 element

Answer (score 6):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) offers an O(n) solution to group objects by attribute:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class X:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

my_list = [X(1), X(2), X(3), X(2), X(3), X(3)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in my_list:
    d[i.param].append(i)
```

The result indicates one object with `param == 1`, two objects with `param == 2` and three objects with `param == 3`:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {1: [<__main__.X at 0x855eb70>],
             2: [<__main__.X at 0x855e588>, <__main__.X at 0x856ae48>],
             3: [<__main__.X at 0x856af60>, <__main__.X at 0x856ad68>, <__main__.X at 0x856acf8>]})
```

To extract *pairs* of objects with the same attribute, you need only to filter items in the dictionary with a value with length greater than 1. Then use `itertools.combinations` to extract all combinations for these keys.

Comment: grouping by attribute.. Ingenious