# Split/partition list based on invariant/hash?

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a list `[a1,21,...]` and would like to split it based on the value of a function `f(a)`.
For example if the input is the list `[0,1,2,3,4]` and the function `def f(x): return x % 3`,
I would like to return a list `[0,3], [1,4], [2]`, since the first group all takes values `0` under `f`, the 2nd group take value `1`, etc...

Something like this works:
`return [[x for x in lst if f(x) == val] for val in set(map(f,lst))]`,

But it does not seem optimal (nor pythonic) since the inner loop unnecessarily scans the entire list and computes same f values of the elements several times.
I'm looking for a solution that would compute the value of `f` ideally once for every element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not irrationally ;-) set on a one-liner, it's straightforward:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [0,1,2,3,4]
f = lambda x: x % 3

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in lst:
    d[f(x)].append(x)
print(list(d.values()))
```

displays what you want.  `f()` is executed `len(lst)` times, which can't be beat

EDIT:  or, if you must:

```
from itertools import groupby
print([[pair[1] for pair in grp]
       for ignore, grp in
       groupby(sorted((f(x), x) for x in lst),
               key=lambda pair: pair[0])])
```

That doesn't require that `f()` produce values usable as dict keys, but incurs the extra expense of a sort, and is close to incomprehensible.  Clarity is much more Pythonic than striving for one-liners.

Comment: Would someone care to explain their downvote?  I'd like to hear it.  It answers the OP's question, in two different ways that do what they asked for.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I like the 1st solution. Was not aware of the defaultdict class, very useful!

Comment: Yup, `defaultdict` can be handy.  With a regular dict, you could test for whether the key already exists first, or do `d.setdefault(f(x), []).append(x)` without testing first.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Peters is right, and here is a mentioned `setdefault` and another `itertool.groupby` option.

**Given**

```
import itertools as it


iterable = range(5)
keyfunc = lambda x: x % 3
```

**Code**

*[`setdefault`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm)*

```
d = {}
for x in iterable:
    d.setdefault(keyfunc(x), []).append(x)

list(d.values())
```

*[`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)*

```
[list(g) for _, g in it.groupby(sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc), key=keyfunc)]
```

See also [more on `itertools.groupby`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873519/4531270)