# How to combine similar characters in a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine similar characters that are next to each other that are in a list. I was wondering if there was a Python way to do it? Here's an example:

```
test = 'hello###_world###test#test123##'
splitter = re.split("(#)", test)
splitter = filter(None, splitter)
```

Which returns this in the splitter variable:

```
['hello', '#', '#', '#', '_world', '#', '#', '#', 'test', '#', 'test123', '#', '#']
```

I'm trying to combine the hashes so the list turns into this:

```
['hello', '###', '_world', '###', 'test', '#', 'test123', '##']
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want to combine similar characters your result must be `['h’, ‘e', 'll', 'o', '###'...]`. In your case you split the string by repeating `#`.

Comment: `re.split` with the right pattern or [`itertools.groupby`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby/45873519#45873519) in general should do it.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
splitter = re.split("(#+)", test)
```

Comment: It gives an empty string at the end.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar With `splitter = filter(None, splitter)` (as in the original post), it does not.

Comment: Yep.  I'd just make a habit to use raw strings in general with regex patterns, e.g.  `r"(#+)".

Answer (score 6):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
test = 'hello###_world###test#test123##'
new_result = [''.join(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(test, key=lambda x:x == '#')]
```

Output:

```
['hello', '###', '_world', '###', 'test', '#', 'test123', '##']
```

You can also use `re.findall`:

```
import re
result = re.findall('#+|[^#]+', test)
```

Output:

```
['hello', '###', '_world', '###', 'test', '#', 'test123', '##']
```

Comment: This one also does the job. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Add + at the end of the regular expression and filtering None values will do the trick

```
>>> import re
>>> test = 'hello###_world###test#test123##'
>>> splitter = re.split("(#+)", test)
>>> splitter
['hello', '###', '_world', '###', 'test', '#', 'test123', '##', '']
>>> splitter = list(filter(None, splitter))
>>> splitter
['hello', '###', '_world', '###', 'test', '#', 'test123', '##']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine every similar character in a list.['h', 'eee', 'lll', 'oo', '#########', '_', 'w', 'r', 'd', 'tttt', 'ss', '1', '2', '3'] like this so you can use this.

```
def combine(s):
dict={}
for i in s:
    key = dict.keys()
    if i in key:
        dict[i]+=1
    else:
        dict[i]=1
v,k = list(dict.values()),list(dict.keys())
product =[]
for i,j in zip(v,k):
    product.append(i*j)
print(product)`enter code here 
s = 'hello###_world###test#test123##'    
count(s)
```

**OUTPUT :** ['h', 'eee', 'lll', 'oo', '#########', '_', 'w', 'r', 'd', 'tttt', 'ss', '1', '2', '3']