# How to split same key value dictionary into a list of dictionaries with those equal keys in different list?

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically I want to group all the dictionaries from the list message with the same key (`name`) in different lists. How should I proceed?

I was thinking about doing some kind of two loops but nothing seems to work.

```
messages={('name': FLR345, 'latitude': 34.244, 'longitude': -23.564), ('name': FLR33, 'latitude': 34.24432, 'longitude': -24.53),('name': FLR345, 'latitude': 35.244, 'longitude': -26.564), ('name': FLR31, 'latitude': 30.244, 'longitude': -22.564)}
```

## I want something like this

```
Drone1={('name': FLR345, 'latitude': 34.244, 'longitude': -23.564),'name': FLR345, 'latitude': 35.244, 'longitude': -26.564)}
Drone2={('name': FLR33, 'latitude': 34.24432, 'longitude': -24.53)}
Drone3={('name': FLR31, 'latitude': 30.244, 'longitude': -22.564)}
```

```
def split
for i in range(len(messages))
    for j in range(len(messages))
        if .......
        Dronei=....
```

Comment: Is `messages` a list or a `set`?  And it looks like you are treating `tuples` like dictionaries inside?  Can you create a sample input that is actually valid python?

Comment: See: [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do…)

Comment: The sample `messages` that you provided is not in a valid format e.g. `('name': FLR345, 'latitude': 34.244, 'longitude': -23.564)` is not valid and `FLR345` needs to be in quotes unless it's an object.  Please provide a valid sample of your data.

Comment: messages={('name': 'FLR345', 'latitude': 34.244, 'longitude': -23.564), ('name': 'FLR33', 'latitude': 34.24432, 'longitude': -24.53),('name': FLR345, 'latitude': 35.244, 'longitude': -26.564), ('name': 'FLR31', 'latitude': 30.244, 'longitude': -22.564)}     Sorry I forgot the ' '.

Comment: The data you provided is not a valid. Python will give syntax error at :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did not completely understand your messages data structure, I made an assumption from your description that it might be a tuple containing dictionaries as elements (rather than the vice versa which is what your question contains). If that is the case, below solution might work, you may have to make a couple changes though, but the idea looks to work fine:

1. Map distinct names to a group name and form a dictionary out of them like 'FLR345' to 'Drone0', 'FLR33' to 'Drone1' etc
2. Go through each element in messages tuple and see if the name already has a group assigned
3. If assigned, just append that message dictionary element to that group
4. Else add them as new entries

   ```
   messages = ({'name': 'FLR345', 'latitude': 34.244, 'longitude': -23.564},
           {'name': 'FLR33', 'latitude': 34.24432, 'longitude': -24.53},
           {'name': 'FLR345', 'latitude': 35.244, 'longitude': -26.564},
           {'name': 'FLR31', 'latitude': 30.244, 'longitude': -22.564})
   messages_grouped = {}
   name_to_message_group = {}
   for i in range(len(messages)):
       #check if the current message name has a group assigned
        if messages[i]['name'] in  name_to_message_group.keys():
            #if yes, append the current message to existing group
            messages_grouped[name_to_message_group[messages[i]['name']]] += (messages[i],)
        else:
            #else add the name to group mapping first
           name_to_message_group[messages[i]['name']] = 'Drone' + str(i)
           #then add the group and message as new elements
           messages_grouped['Drone' + str(i)] = tuple()
           messages_grouped['Drone' + str(i)] += (messages[i],)
   print (messages_grouped)
   ```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Huge thanks.

Comment: Great ! Please accept the answer if you feel it worked for the question you had asked.