# Get the last date of the month from a given list of dates

Tags: python

I have a list of dates in a csv file which I would like to extract the last date of each month using python.

For example,
03/08/2019
20/08/2019
30/12/2020
31/12/2020

The output should be 20/08/2019 & 31/12/2020

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem yourself yet?

Comment: would it be possible to use pandas?

Comment: is the example a string (Eg: `03/08/2019 20/08/2019 30/12/2020 31/12/2020`) or array (Eg: `["03/08/2019", "20/08/2019",...]`)?

Comment: `last date of each month`. and the input and the output you have provided, can you review them and get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` the list of dates based on year, month and date and then convert it to a dict with key as the month and year, which would retain only the last date for a given month and year and then get dict's values as a list

```
>>> lst = ['03/08/2019', '20/08/2019', '30/12/2020', '31/12/2020']
>>> list({date.split('/', 1)[-1]:date for date in sorted(lst, key=lambda date: date.split('/')[::-1])}.values())
['20/08/2019', '31/12/2020']
```

Or using `datetime`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> to_date = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y')
>>> list({to_date(d).replace(day=1):d for d in sorted(lst, key=to_date)}.values())
['20/08/2019', '31/12/2020']
```

Comment: Would be simpler to parse into dates using a package of some sort, `pandas` or `datetime`.

Comment: @YaakovBressler. Updated my answer using `datetime`

Answer (score 0):

@PythonNovice. I'd suggest starting with itertools.groupBy which is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby).
You've got to open that file, parse the lines, sort the data, group it by months and take the last element of each month. Is there a specific part of that with which you're having a problem?