# Enter the values in a list to an empty dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to enter the values in a list into an empty dictionary but I keep getting error messages and I don't know what I did wrong.

My list `lst` looks like this:

```
[[123,456],
[123,123],
[123,567],
[234,344],
[234,345],
[234,988]...]
```

I was asked to first create an empty dictionary that contains the first number from `lst` (should look like this `123:[],234:[]`), then enter the second number that follows the first number in the list into the dictionary and the dictionary should look something like `{123:[456,567],234:[344,345,988]...}` (if the first number equals to the second number, the second number should not be included)

I created an empty dictionary and then print the dictionary values for the numbers using the following code:

```
dic = dict((i, []) for i in lst)

for key, value in dic.items():
    if key in lst:
        print(key, ":", value)
```

When I tried to put the values from `lst` into the dictionary using the following code:

```
for w in lst:
    if w[0] in dic.keys() and w[0] != w[1]:
        dic[w[0]].append(w[1])

lst2 = []
for a in lst[0:10]:
    lst2.append(dic[a])
print(lst2)
```

I got an error message below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-610d94e48548> in <module>
      8 
      9 for w in idList:
---> 10     if w[0] in dic.keys() and w[0] != w[1]:
     11         dic[w[0]].append(w[1])
     12 

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

**Does anyone know what happened there and how can I solve this?**

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: btw you missed a coma in lst

Comment: somewere you must inserted an integer into idList

Comment: The code in your stack trace differs from what you provided in the question

Comment: also see my answer for corrected lst comprehension, yours is incorrect

Comment: I can imagine idList is just list of first elements

Comment: [123,234 ... ] or {123:[], 234:[]...}

Answer (score 0):

Most close to your solution:

```
dic = {i[0]: [] for i in lst}

for w in lst:
    if w[0] != w[1] 
        dic[w[0]].append(w[1])
```

Note. To do the first step more fancy you can use defaultdict and groupby for second [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[123,456],
[123,123],
[123,567],
[234,344],
[234,345],
[234,988]]

dic = {} #empty dictionary

# creating dictionary with inner list first element as key and value as list
for i in l:
    dic.update({i[0]:[]})

# adding the second value to the corresponding key in list
for i in l:
    dic[i[0]].append(i[1])


print(dic)
```

output

```
{123: [456, 123, 567], 234: [344, 345, 988]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [[123,456],[123,123],[123,567],[234,344],[234,345],[234,988]]

dic = dict((i[0], []) for i in lst)

for i in lst:
   if i[0] != i[1]:
       dic[i[0]].append(i[1])
```

Comment: can you please add few lines of explanation @kartheek