# Python - itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-itertools

Just having trouble with itertools.groupby. Given a list of dictionaries,

```
my_list = [
{'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200, 'shares': 100},
{'name': 'stock2', 'price': 1.2, 'shares': 1000},
{'name': 'stock3', 'price': 0.05, 'shares': 200000},
{'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200.2, 'shares': 50}]
```

From this list, I was hoping to create a dictionary, where the key is the name of the stock, and the value is a list of dictionaries of that stock, for example:

```
{'stock1': [{'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200, 'shares': 100}, {'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200.2, 'shares': 50}] }
```

I ran this code:

```
by_name = { name: list(items) for name, items in itertools.groupby(
            my_list, key=lambda x: x['name'])}
```

, and this is the result I got:

```
 {'stock1': [{'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200.2, 'shares': 50}],
 'stock2': [{'name': 'stock2', 'price': 1.2, 'shares': 1000}],
 'stock3': [{'name': 'stock3', 'price': 0.05, 'shares': 200000}]}
```

For stock1, I'm expecting 2 items in the list but it only has the latest entry from the original my_list. Can anyone please point out where the mistake is? Thank you!

Comment: you need to sort your initial list by stock before using groupBy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't how [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20groupby#itertools.groupby) works. From the manual:

> It generates a break or new group **every time the value of the key function changes** (which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted the data using the same key function)

So to achieve the type of grouping you want, you need to sort `my_list` first:

```py
import itertools

my_list = [
{'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200, 'shares': 100},
{'name': 'stock2', 'price': 1.2, 'shares': 1000},
{'name': 'stock3', 'price': 0.05, 'shares': 200000},
{'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200.2, 'shares': 50}
]

my_list.sort(key=lambda x:x['name'])

by_name = { name: list(items) for name, items in itertools.groupby(
            my_list, key=lambda x: x['name'])}

print(by_name)
```

Output

```py
{'stock1': [{'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200, 'shares': 100},
            {'name': 'stock1', 'price': 200.2, 'shares': 50}],
 'stock2': [{'name': 'stock2', 'price': 1.2, 'shares': 1000}],
 'stock3': [{'name': 'stock3', 'price': 0.05, 'shares': 200000}]
}
```

Comment: I see. Wow thank you. This is my first question and was answered in less than 5 minutes, and I was stuck in this one for 1 hour until now! I initially thought my previous code was fine because itertools.groupby will produce an iterator any way and wont need to be sorted. Thanks again!