# How to join strings from a list only if they can be joined continuously without any integer in between?

Tags: python, loops

I have a list that can contain strings and integers, but I want to join all adjacent strings, only if there is no integer between those strings.
For example :

```
list_a = [0, 0, "c", "a", "k", "e", 0, 0, "y", "o", "u", 0]
taken = []
for let in list_a:
    if let == 0:
        pass
    else:
        taken.append(let)

word = "".join(taken)
print(word)

>> cakeyou
```

I want to get either "cake" or "you" or both as two words. "Cakeyou" should not be an output because to get "cakeyou" the loop would move pass two zeros when it should stop the moment it meets any zero after reading some strings.
Another important detail is that the words cake or you could be anywhere in the list, here I chose the index for simplicity (so slicing would not be a viable option)

Comment: _the loop would move pass two zeros_ which is exactly what You are doing with `if let == 0: pass`

Comment: I would use [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). See [How do I use itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_a = [0, 0, "c", "a", "k", "e", 0, 0, "y", "o", "u", 0]
taken = []
temp = ""
for let in list_a:
    if isinstance(let, int):
        if temp:
            taken.append(temp)
            temp = ""
    else:
        temp += let

if temp:
    taken.append(temp)

print(taken)
#>>>['cake', 'you']
```

Comment: This is perfect !

Comment: I got a tip so the last if statement is not required. Right after declaring list_a, added list_a.append(0).

Answer (score 1):

```py
list_a = [0, 0, "c", "a", "k", "e", 0, 0, "y", "o", "u", 0]
taken = []; toadd = ''; open = False
for c, l in enumerate(list_a):
    if type(l) != int:
        open = True
        toadd += l
    else:
        if open:
            taken.append(toadd)
        toadd = ''
        open = False
    if c == len(list_a)-1:
        if open:
            taken.append(toadd)
        toadd = ''
print(taken)
#>>>['cake', 'you']
```

Comment: this seems way too complex for the issue it is solving tho a solution nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Is this suitable for you?

```
list_a = [0, 0, "c", "a", "k", "e", 0, 0, "y", "o", "u", 0]
words = []

word = ""
for letter in list_a:
    if letter == 0 and word == "":
        pass
    elif letter == 0:
        words.append(word)
        word = ""
    else:
        word += letter

print(words)
#>>>['cake', 'you']
```

Comment: If you want to check for integers instead of just "0", you can replace if letter == 0 with if isinstance(letter, int)

Sorry for awful formatting in this comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which splits sequences based upon some key. If we say the key is that the value is a `str`, then we get a sequence of groups of `str` values. We also get a value saying whether the key evaluated `True` or `False`. We can then filter out the groups of `str` values and the groups of `int` values:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> values = [0, 0, "c", "a", "k", "e", 0, 0, "y", "o", "u", 0]

>>> for keep, group in groupby(values, key=lambda value: isinstance(value, str)):
...     if keep:
...         print(''.join(group))
cake
you
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, you put a space when the value is an `int`, then join, and use `strip()` to emove leading and padding spaces

```
list_a = [0, 0, "c", "a", "k", "e", 0, 0, "y", "o", "u", 0]
taken = []
for let in list_a:
    if isinstance(let, int):
        taken.append(" ")
    else:
        taken.append(let)

word = "".join(taken).strip()
print(word)  # 'cake  you'
```

Comment: I suggest replacing `word = ''.join(taken).strip()` with `word = ' '.join(word for word in "".join(taken).split() if word != '')` which is a bit longer but gets rid of unwanted spaces, for example in the case there are a lot of integers between strings, so that printing out it doesn't produce a massive space

Comment: @Supernyv you can think about accepting the answer so (green tick onleft) ;)

Answer (score -2):

My solution:
make everything a string, strip leading and trailing zeros and split by double-zero. Than just grab the first entry. (Error handling for invalid input not included)

```
list_a = [0, 0, "c", "a", "k", "e", 0, 0, "y", "o", "u", 0]
all_stringified = [str(a) for a in list_a]
word = ''.join(all_stringified).strip('0').split('00')[0]
print(word)

>> cake
```

For history my first answer:

My suggestion is to use a filter within a list comprehension:

```
list_a = [0, 0, "c", "a", "k", "e", 0, 0, "y", "o", "u", 0]
taken = [e for e in list_a if isinstance(e, str)]
word = "".join(taken)
print(word)

>> cakeyou
```

Comment: _"Cakeyou"_ should not be an output

Comment: You coudl do this tho: `[e if isinstance(e, str) else ' ' for e in list_a]`

Comment: Yep sorry, did not read everything....edited to new solution.