# Remove consecutive duplicate words from a comma separated string

Tags: python

If I have a string in a column that is separated by commas:

"apple, apple, banana, pear, apple"

How would I remove only consecutive duplicated words? My desired output would look like this:

"apple, banana, pear, apple"

The words in the string are separated by commas. I understand in [this post] [How do I use itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby) if the words are in a list this will work, but my issue is slightly different in that it is a single string and there are commas after each word. Thank you in advance.

Comment: is it a string in a list or a list of strings or a single string?

Comment: Its a string in a column in a data frame

Comment: You could make use of `itertools.groupby()`

Comment: @Barmar How would I go about this if the string contains commas? 'apple, apple, pear, apple' is one string and there are commas within the string?

Comment: Regarding the edit, you just need to convert the string to a list and back. Do you know how to use `str.split()` and `str.join()`? If not, you really should learn. In short it'd be something like `sep = ', '; sep.join(remove_consecutive_duplicates(string.split(sep)))`. Or do you want a Pandas-specific solution? (I'm not sure if one exists, but I do know Pandas has vectorized string operations.)

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you. After playing around with it I finally got what I needed.