# Partition a list items using a list containing partition numbers

Tags: python, partition, group

Given a list

```
lst=['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','d']
```

and a list 'l' containing partition numbers

```
l=[2,3,1,2]
```

what I want is

```
partitioned_lst=[['a','a'],['b','b','b'],['c'],['d','d']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the characters are grouped? If not, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
partitioned_lst=[]
i=0
for n in l:
    partitioned_lst.append(lst[i:i+n])
    i+=n
partitioned_lst
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner just for fun

```
print([lst[sum(l[:index]):sum(l[:index])+num] for index, num in enumerate(l)])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `groupby` (see Peter Wood's comment) because you need `l`:

```
lst=['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','d']
l=[2,3,1,2]

it = iter(lst)
result = [[next(it) for _ in range(n)] for n in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst=['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','d']
l=[2,3,1,2]
s = 0
Res=[]
for i in l:
  Res.append(lst[s: s+i])
  s += i
print(Res)
```

Output

```
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is a solution using the relatively new [assignment expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) (python ≥ 3.8):

```
x=0
partitioned_lst = [lst[x:(x:=x+y)] for y in l]
```

*NB. I wouldn't use this in production code as it depends on the outer scope*

output:

```
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'd']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one that works for arbitrary iterables:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> [list(islice(it, n)) for it in [iter(lst)] for n in l]
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'd']]
>>>
```

Although, probably would be cleaner as a generator:

```
def partition_by(iterable, partitions):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for n in partitions:
        yield list(islice(it, n))
```

And use like:

```
>>> list(partition_by(lst, l))
[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'd']]
```

Note, this approach will not error out and keep going if the iterator is exhausted:

```
>>> list(partition_by(lst, [10, 10, 10]))
[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd'], [], []]
```

If this behavior is undesirable:

```
def partition_by(iterable, partitions, strict=True):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for n in partitions:
        part = list(islice(it, n))
        if not part and strict:
            raise ValueError("iterable ran out of items early")
        yield part
```

Would do it.

Type annotated:

```
import typing
from collections.abc import Iterable

def partition_by(
    iterable: Iterable[T], 
    partitions: Iterable[int], 
    strict: bool=True
) -> Iterable[list[T]]:
    it = iter(iterable)
    for n in partitions:
        part = list(islice(it, n))
        if not part and strict:
            raise ValueError("iterable ran out of items early")
        yield part
```