# Building a number compression algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem:

Consider a simple number compression algorithm that works as follows:

```
111155522500 -> [('1', 4), ('5', 3), ('2', 2), ('5', 1), ('O', 2)]
```

The algorithm goes from left to right through each digit and returns a list of two-element tuples. Each tuple consists of a digit and the number of repetitions of a given
digit until the next, different digit in the number is encountered.

Implement a function called compress () that compresses number as described above.

Examples:

```
[IN]: compress(lll)
[OUT]: [('l', 3)]
[IN]: conpress(1000000)
[OUT]: [('1', 1), ('O', 6)]
[IN]: conpress(10005000)
[OUT]: [('1', 1), ('O', 3), ('5', 1), ('O', 3)]
```

My code:

```
#para funcionar, é e necessário acrescentar um caracter que não  existe ao final da string!
def compress(elemento):
    elemento = str(elemento)
    elemento = elemento +"§"# the code only works if I add some char not in the string
    saida = []
    #cont = 0
    contagem = []
    
    for index,ele in enumerate(elemento):
        ele = str(ele)
        #print(f"contagem: {contagem}")
        if len(contagem) == 0 or ele in contagem:
            contagem.append(ele)
       
        if ele not in contagem :
            saida.append((elemento[index-1],len(contagem)) )
            contagem = []
            contagem.append(ele)                      
        
    return saida



compress('1000500011')
```

OUT:

```
[('1', 1), ('0', 3), ('5', 1), ('0', 3), ('1', 2)]
```

The problem: The code only works if I add some char not in the string as "§"
Could someone help to solve this problem  using the itertools built-in module and the groupby and without this modules?

Comment: what's missing, to avoid the end-of-sequence special character, is `saida.append((elemento[index-1],len(contagem)) )` after your loop has completed

Comment: also, `contagem` is usually replaced with a current character pointer, and a current count of occurences. Otherwise `ele in contagem` can become expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrections to your code with '> Edit---' comments to highlight changes.

**Code**

```
def compress(elemento):
    elemento = str(elemento)  # > Edit-----not necessary, since already a string
    
    # > Edit-----Remove adding last character
    #elemento = elemento +"§"# the code only works if I add some char not in the string
    
    saida = []
    #cont = 0
    contagem = []
    
    for index,ele in enumerate(elemento):

        #ele = str(ele)   # > Edit-----not necessary, since already a string
        #print(f"contagem: {contagem}")
        #f len(contagem) == 0 or ele in contagem:     # > Edit-----Inefficient to check entire list
        if len(contagem) == 0 or ele == contagem[-1]: #            More efficient just to compare last element in list
            contagem.append(ele)
       
        #if ele not in contagem :   # > Edit-----Inefficient to check entire list
        if ele != contagem[-1]:     #             More efficient just to compare last element in list
            #saida.append((elemento[index-1],len(contagem)) ) # EDIT---incorrect index
            saida.append((elemento[index-1],len(contagem)) )  # EDIT---index reference correct character
            contagem = []
            contagem.append(ele)   
          
    # > Edit-----Not having next if block caused your error
    #             Add last contagem  if it exists
    if contagem:
        #saida.append((elemento[index-1], len(contagem)) )
        saida.append((elemento[index-1], len(contagem)) )  # EDIT---incorrect index
        saida.append((elemento[index], len(contagem)) )    # EDIT---index references to correct character
    return saida

compress('1000500011')
```

**Output**

```
[('1', 1), ('0', 3), ('5', 1), ('0', 3), ('1', 2)]
```

**Code Refactoring**

Code can be simplified to the following:

```
def compress(elements):
    stack = []
    for ele in elements:
        if not stack or stack[-1][0] != ele:
            stack.append((ele, 1)) 
        else:
            stack[-1] = (stack[-1][0], stack[-1][1] + 1)
            
    return stack
```

Comment: thanks! There is a bug in my code corrected by you: for exemple:  IN: compress('1000500016') _> OUT: [('1', 1), ('0', 3), ('5', 1), ('0', 3), ('1', 1), ('1', 1)]. Could you help?

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look.

Comment: @EdS -- made correction to your corrected code.  To get the current character we need `elemento[index]`, not `elemento[index-1]`, This is because in `for index,ele in enumerate(elemento):` index goes from 0 (first chaaracter) to len(elemento)-1 (last character).  Let me know if there are other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straight forward with `itertools`.

```
def compress(number):
    return [
        (c, sum(1 for _ in g))
        for c, g in itertools.groupby(str(number))
    ]
```

demo:

```
>>> compress(10005000)
[('1', 1), ('0', 3), ('5', 1), ('0', 3)]
```

Comment: thanks. Could you explain the code?

Comment: @EdS sure, if you have a specific question?

Comment: I did not understand the use of itertools!

Comment: is there a specific part of the documentation that you don't understand?

Comment: @EdS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby

Answer (score 2):

The earlier post is a perfect example of `groupby`.  But if you're open to *more_itertools*, here is another version: `run_length`.  It basically doing something similar with *groupby* -  compresses an *iterable* with run-length encoding. It yields groups of repeated items with the count of how many times they were repeated:

It even provides corresponding *decode* to decompress the compressed one.  Please check it out.  So there is *no need to reinvent the wheels...*

```
from more_itertools import run_length

num = 10005000

compressed = list(run_length.encode(str(num)))
```

Output:

```
[('1', 1), ('0', 3), ('5', 1), ('0', 3)]
```

```
So running it in IDE like this:
>>> num = 10005000
>>> compressed = list(run_length.encode(str(num)))
>>> compressed
[('1', 1), ('0', 3), ('5', 1), ('0', 3)]
>>> run_length.decode(compressed)
<itertools.chain object at 0x039931A8>
>>> list(run_length.decode(compressed))
['1', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0']
>>> num = [int(x) for x in run_length.decode(compressed)]
>>> num
[1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

An `itertools` approach:

```
from itertools import groupby

def compress(n):
   return [(grp_id, len(list(grp))) for grp_id, grp in groupby(str(n))]

n = 111155522500
print(compress(n))
```

Just for fun, a decompress function:

```
def decompress(n_compress):
    return int(''.join(map(str.__mul__, *zip(*n_compress))))
```