# Split numpy array into groups of the same number

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have an array :

```
A = np.array([1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,5,5])
```

I want to do some function that will split A into smaller arrays (or lists, either works - I will use lists in the example easier to write), each made up of a chunk of the same number.

```
B = stackoverflowgeniusfunc(A)
B
[[1],[2,2,2],[3,3],[1,1,1],[4,4,4,4,4],[5,5]]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use itertools.groupby()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy does not support variable size dimensions so your expected output cannot be a numpy array.  It can be a normal Python list however.  groupby would be the usual way to obtain it:

```
from itertools import groupby

A = [1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,5,5]
G = [g for _,(*g,) in groupby(A)]

print(G)
[[1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 1, 1], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5]]
```

*Note: this would also work if A were a numpy array but there is no point in using numpy for this unless you need is elsewhere*

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Simple and perfect thank you! You are correct that A is a numpy array for use elsewhere, the compatibility with arrays and lists is neat though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to group the similar objects together, you can do something like this.

```
    def stackoverflowgeniusfunc(arr):
    result = []
    current_chunk = [arr[0]]

    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == arr[i-1]:
            current_chunk.append(arr[i])
        else:
            result.append(current_chunk)
            current_chunk = [arr[i]]

    result.append(current_chunk)
    return result
```

The function splits the array A into smaller arrays/lists, where each chunk consists of consecutive elements of the same number.

**PS:** You can also use numpy's

> np.split()

function with a custom condition to split the array whenever the value changes

```
    import numpy as np
    
    A = np.array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5])
    
    # Find the indices where the value changes
    change_indices = np.where(A[1:] != A[:-1])[0] + 1
    
    # Split the array based on the change indices
    B = np.split(A, change_indices)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np
A=np.array([1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,5,5])

def stackoverflowgeniusfunc(a):
  return [list(group[1]) for group in groupby(A)]

stackoverflowgeniusfunc(A)

#output
[[1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 1, 1], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5]]
```